# how to take foreign key fields in actual form validation, DJANGO

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

Thanks for your time:

i want to set Validation Error with data that is already written in other modelclass.

Models.py

```
class People(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='person')
    birthday = models.DateField()
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.user)


class Pets(models.Model):
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    custo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    tipo = models.SmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.pessoa, self.nome)
```

Forms.py:

```
class PetForm3(forms.ModelForm): #SELECIONAR FORM PELO FORMS.PY
    field_choices = [
        (1, 'CACHORRO'),
        (2, 'GATO'),
        (3, 'ANDORINHA')
    ]

    nome = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    custo = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    tipo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=field_choices)

    class Meta:
        prefix = 'pet'
        model = Pets
        fields = ['nome', 'custo', 'tipo']

    def clean_tipo(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get("tipo")
        data_pessoa = self.cleaned_data.get("pessoa")
        slug = slugify(data_pessoa)
        if slug.startswith('a'):
            data == 2
            raise forms.ValidationError('nomes com A nao podem ter gatos')
        return data
```

i got these two models and the Pets is a ManytoOne to People i'd like to take attributes of People like birthday and cpf in the clean_method of PetForm3.

and like to get the ''pessoa'', whithout having to display, field from Pets on the clean method either.

i'm able to achieve something like that with request.user in views.py but i'd like to get it in clean_method at forms.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not the best solution, but you can do this

```
def clean_tipo(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get("tipo")
        pk = self.cleaned_data.get("pessoa")
        pessoa = People.objects.get(pk=pk)
        birthday = pessoa.birthday
        cpf = pessoa.cpf
        slug = slugify(data_pessoa)
        if slug.startswith('a'):
            data == 2
            raise forms.ValidationError('nomes com A nao podem ter gatos')
        return data
```

Comment: People matching query does not exist.
i've tried this too

Comment: actually the self.cleaned_data.get('pessoa') will return the actual object, so you can process it directly `pessoa = self.cleaned_data.get('pessoa')` , and then you can get the other fields `pessoa.birthday`

Comment: kkkkkkk it actually worked. i don't know why but i had to erase my whole database to work the code propperly. thank you sr